# Threejs geometry position

Tags: javascript, three.js, dhtmlx

I have created some geometry and some functions to move and detect it.
 It works perfect but now I have inserted it into a javascript UI library http://dhtmlx.com/ and doesn't work well. The problem is this: for example using raycaster, it find intersection with geometry also when geometry isn't under the mouse. It looks like all geometries are moved up from original position  and draw is a fake.

I made an example in this url : http://www.felpone.netsons.org/web-threejs%20-%20Copia/contact_manager/prova1.html. You can see the complete code in the console.

Below only a part of code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Stereos + Three.js</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-  scale=1.0">
<script src="codebase/dhtmlx.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" href="codebase/dhtmlx.css"> 
<link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" href="style.css"> 
</head>


<body>

<script src="threejs/Three.js"></script>
<script src="threejs/Detector.js"></script>
<script src="threejs/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="threejs/BufferAttribute.js"></script>
<script src="threejs/BufferGeometry.js"></script>
<script src="threejs/EdgesHelper.js"></script>
<script src="threejs/THREEx.KeyboardState.js"></script>
<script src="threejs/THREEx.FullScreen.js"></script>
<script src="threejs/THREEx.WindowResize.js"></script>

  <!-- ------------------------------------------------------------->


<div id="ThreeJS" style="position: absolute; left:0px; top:0px"></div>

<!-- <input type="button" style="position: absolute; left:0px; top:0px; z-index:1;" onclick="params()"/> -->

<script>
   var FONT_SIZE = 22;
var container, scene, camera, renderer, controls, scene_text,raycaster, projector, mouse2D;
var plane,INTERSECTED, SELECTED;
var verticesSphere = [];
var geometryContainer=[];
var offset=offset = new THREE.Vector3();
var layout,menu,toolbar;

dhtmlx.image_path = "codebase/imgs/";


dhtmlxEvent(window,"load",function(){ 
        var layout = new dhtmlXLayoutObject(document.body,"1C"); 
        layout.cells("a").setText("Contacts"); 
        var obj = document.getElementById("ThreeJS");
        layout.cells("a").attachObject(obj);




        menu = layout.attachMenu();                                                //initializes   dhtmlxMenu
        menu.setIconsPath("icons/");                                               //sets the   path to custom icons
        menu.loadXML("data/menu.xml");                                             //loads items   from the "data/menu.xml" file to the menu

        toolbar = layout.attachToolbar();                                          //initializes  dhtmlxToolbar
        toolbar.setIconsPath("icons/");                                            //sets the  path to custom images
        toolbar.loadXML("data/toolbar.xml");                                       //loads items from the "data/toolbar.xml" file to the toolbar
    }); 




init();
render();



function init() 
{
    // SCENE
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene_text = new THREE.Scene();

    // CAMERA
    var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth-5, SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight-5;
    var VIEW_ANGLE = 45, ASPECT = SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, NEAR = 0.01, FAR = 20000;
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR);
    var r = 4, phi = Math.PI/4, theta = Math.PI/4;
    camera.position.set(r*Math.cos(phi)*Math.sin(theta),r*Math.sin(phi),  r*Math.cos(phi)*Math.cos(theta));

    // RENDERER
    if ( Detector.webgl )
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {antialias:true} );
    else
            renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer(); 
    renderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    renderer.autoClear = false;

    // CONTAINER
    container = document.getElementById( 'ThreeJS' );
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    // EVENTS
    THREEx.WindowResize(renderer, camera);
    THREEx.FullScreen.bindKey({ charCode : 'm'.charCodeAt(0) });

    // CONTROLS
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
    controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );
    controls.target = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);






    // LIGHTS
    var light1 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
    light1.position.set(0,1000,1000);
    scene.add(light1);
    var light2 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
    light2.position.set(0,-1000,-1000);
    scene.add(light2);

    /////////////
    // OBJECTS //
    /////////////





    geometry0 = new THREE.Geometry();
    geometry0.vertices = [new THREE.Vector3(0.5, -0.5, 0.5), new THREE.Vector3(-0.5, -0.5, 0.5),  new THREE.Vector3(-0.5, -0.5, -0.5), new THREE.Vector3(0.5, -0.5, -0.5), new THREE.Vector3(0.5, 0.5,  0.5), new THREE.Vector3(-0.5, 0.5, 0.5), new THREE.Vector3(-0.5, 0.5, -0.5), new THREE.Vector3(0.5,  0.5, -0.5)]; 
    geometry0.faces = [new THREE.Face3(3, 2, 1), new THREE.Face3(3, 1, 0), new THREE.Face3(4, 5, 6), new THREE.Face3(4, 6, 7), new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 5), new THREE.Face3(0, 5, 4), new THREE.Face3(1, 2, 6), new THREE.Face3(1, 6, 5), new THREE.Face3(2, 3, 7), new THREE.Face3(2, 7, 6), new THREE.Face3(3, 0, 4), new THREE.Face3(3, 4, 7)]; 
    geometry0.computeFaceNormals();
    geometry0.computeVertexNormals();
    var material0 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x39d2dbe7fff39d2, transparent: true,  opacity: 0 });
mesh0 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry0, material0);
    scene.add(mesh0);
    egh0 = new THREE.EdgesHelper( mesh0, 0x000 );
    egh0.material.linewidth = 2;
    scene.add( egh0 );








geometry1 = new THREE.Geometry()
geometry1.vertices = [new THREE.Vector3(-3.43321e-11, -0.5, 0.5), new THREE.Vector3(1.29324e-12, -0.5, -0.5), new THREE.Vector3(-0.5, -0.5, 4.98925e-11), new THREE.Vector3(-0.5, -0.166667, -0.5), new THREE.Vector3(-0.5, 0.166667, -0.5), new THREE.Vector3(-0.5, 0.166667, 0.5), new THREE.Vector3(-0.5, -0.166667, 0.5), new THREE.Vector3(0.5, -0.166667, 0.5), new THREE.Vector3(0.5, -0.5, 1.37552e-11), new THREE.Vector3(0.5, -0.166667, -0.5), new THREE.Vector3(0.5, 0.166667, -0.5), new THREE.Vector3(-9.97714e-12, 0.5, -0.5), new THREE.Vector3(-0.5, 0.5, 2.6745e-12), new THREE.Vector3(-6.41701e-13, 0.5, 0.5), new THREE.Vector3(0.5, 0.166667, 0.5), new THREE.Vector3(0.5, 0.5, 3.07725e-11)]; 
geometry1.faces = [new THREE.Face3(1, 3, 2), new THREE.Face3(6, 0, 2), new THREE.Face3(7, 8, 0), new THREE.Face3(8, 9, 1), new THREE.Face3(11, 12, 4), new THREE.Face3(12, 13, 5), new THREE.Face3(15, 11, 10), new THREE.Face3(15, 14, 13), new THREE.Face3(2, 0, 8), new THREE.Face3(2, 8, 1), new THREE.Face3(12, 5, 6), new THREE.Face3(12, 6, 2), new THREE.Face3(12, 2, 3), new THREE.Face3(12, 3, 4), new THREE.Face3(14, 7, 0), new THREE.Face3(14, 0, 6), new THREE.Face3(14, 6, 5), new THREE.Face3(14, 5, 13), new THREE.Face3(10, 9, 8), new THREE.Face3(10, 8, 7), new THREE.Face3(10, 7, 14), new THREE.Face3(10, 14, 15), new THREE.Face3(15, 13, 12), new THREE.Face3(15, 12, 11), new THREE.Face3(9, 10, 11), new THREE.Face3(9, 11, 4), new THREE.Face3(9, 4, 3), new THREE.Face3(9, 3, 1)]; 
geometry1.computeFaceNormals();
geometry1.computeVertexNormals();
var material1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00, transparent: true, opacity: 0.5 });
mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry1, material1);
scene.add(mesh1);
egh1 = new THREE.EdgesHelper( mesh1, 0x000 );
egh1.material.linewidth = 2;
scene.add( egh1 );

geometry2 = new THREE.Geometry()
geometry2.vertices = [new THREE.Vector3(0.5, -0.5, 0), new THREE.Vector3(0.5, -0.166667, 0.5), new THREE.Vector3(0, -0.5, 0.5), new THREE.Vector3(0.5, -0.5, 0.5)]; 
geometry2.faces = [new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2), new THREE.Face3(0, 3, 1), new THREE.Face3(1, 3, 2), new THREE.Face3(2, 3, 0)]; 
geometry2.computeFaceNormals();
geometry2.computeVertexNormals();
var material2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffff00 });
mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry2, material2);
scene.add(mesh2);
egh2 = new THREE.EdgesHelper( mesh2, 0x000 );
egh2.material.linewidth = 2;
scene.add( egh2 );




projector = new THREE.Projector();

mouse2D = new THREE.Vector3(0, 10000, 0.5);


plane = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 2000, 2000, 8, 8 ), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(     { color: 0xffff00, opacity: 0.25 } ) );
            plane.visible = false;
            scene.add( plane );


}
```

Comment: how do you get the mouse position? surely not by "mouse2D = new THREE.Vector3(0, 10000, 0.5);" when you actually want to get it from the mouse pointer. perhaps you use window pos and not in the three's canvases space?

if you want help i think you should put a full live demo up, this partial code does not seem helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How can i create full live demo? @antont

Comment: either put an example that demonstrates your problem on your website or to a js sharing system like http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I made an example in this url : http://www.felpone.netsons.org/web-threejs%20-%20Copia/contact_manager/prova1.html @antont